# Convert long numbers to base 256 number system

Tags: javascript, node.js, math, biginteger

I need to convert a number of very large length (may be larger than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`) represented as string, to base 256 number system. 
Something like this:

```js
console.log(convert_to_base_256("10")); //-> [10]
console.log(convert_to_base_256("1024"); //-> [4, 0]
console.log(convert_to_base_256("123456")); //-> [1, 226, 64]
```

I know I could use big integer library, but most of them don't support the base conversion beyond base 62.
What is the best algorithm to do so?

Comment: You can convert it to a base-16 number using some big integer library and then merge every two hexadecimal digits so that you can get a base-256 number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're in luck. The major browsers<sup>*</sup> now support [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) natively, so you can do what you need with some simple arithmetic.

```
let bigString = "123456";
    let bigOne = BigInt(bigString);

    let base256 = [];
    do {
        base256.unshift(Number(bigOne%256n));   // Use Number constructor to cast result
        bigOne = bigOne/256n;
    } while (bigOne)

    console.log(base256);   // [ 1, 226, 64 ]
```

<sup>* I ran this in Firefox 89, Chrome 90 and Edge 90. I couldn't get it to work as an SO snippet, or in JSFiddle.</sup>

Note: this question wasn't originally tagged with [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js) so I didn't consider that. Since the OP has raised the issue, BigInt support was added to NodeJS 10.4, so this code should run with that version and all subsequent ones.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, I found out that older versions of node [don't support BigInt](https://thecodebarbarian.com/an-overview-of-bigint-in-node-js.html) so I'll have to make do by implementing my own functions for long divison and modulo of strings.